# Doctrine 2 Uppercase First Letter

Tags: mysql, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2

I need to uppercase the first letter of word while fetching data using Select query in Doctrine2.

I tried UCASE , but it is not supported in Doctrine 2.

Is there any other way to Uppercase the first letter in Doctrine2 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve same effect by utilizing [Lifecycle Callbacks](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/events.html#lifecycle-callbacks) if doing this on database level is not really required.

For example, in your entity, write a post-load method like this:

```
<?php 
namespace MyApp\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks <-- NOTICE THIS ANNOTATION
 */
class MyEntity
{

   /**
    * @ORM\PostLoad <-- AND THIS
    */
    public function capitalizeField()
    {
        $this->field = mb_ucfirst($this->field);
    }

}
```

> **Update after two years:**
>
> This approach solves the problem. Anyway, in a similar situation I would prefer to change the case **before writing the data** into the database, if possible. I mean that lifecycle callbacks are not free. Another option is changing the case in presentation/view layer. Today, utilizing the whole event mechanism to change the case of a single value sounds overkill to me.

Answer (score 0):

Do it in MySQL, e.g.

```
SELECT CONCAT(UPPER(LEFT(the_field, 1)),LOWER(SUBSTRING(the_field, 2))) FROM the_table
```

or if you don't want to alter the field excpet the first letter:

```
SELECT CONCAT(UPPER(LEFT(the_field, 1)),SUBSTRING(the_field, 2)) FROM the_table
```